# Getting Tabs (Tabhost) working

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I'm trying to turn a single page app into one with tabs. I've looked at various Googled solutions, but none work, and I can't find a 'Tabs - how they work' anywhere! One problem I have when using a 'Googled' answer is a null pointer exception on the Layout of main.xml.

Can anyone help/point me to a decent page?

My code is below.

Thanks,

Martin.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/edtICAO" android:text="    "></EditText>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Brief!" android:id="@+id/btnBrief" android:onClick="btnBriefClick"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btnHome" android:text="Home" android:clickable="true" android:onClick="btnHomeClick"></Button><Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btnChartList" android:text="Charts List" android:onClick="btnChartClick"></Button></LinearLayout><ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"><LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"><TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Metar :" android:id="@+id/txtMetar"></TextView><TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TAF :" android:id="@+id/txtTAF"></TextView></LinearLayout></ScrollView><ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:fillViewport="true" android:isScrollContainer="false" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true" android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" android:visibility="visible" android:layout_height="fill_parent">  
    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtNotam" android:text="NOTAM :"  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@color/black" android:background="@color/white"></TextView>
    </ScrollView>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: [Try looking here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hey martin,
make sure you follow this guide:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

The tutorial is not complete, however. After completing all the steps, open you AndroidManifest.xml file and add the following:

<activity android:name=".TabName" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        </activity>

for every tab (insert appropriate class name instead of TabName). I'm assuming that you will create a separate class for each tab, just like in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had looked at that, but thought it was a bit complex. Having now done the project I realise that's the way it is!!

However, the project will compile and install, but won't run.

On a real phone 'Open' is disabled after installation and the app doesn't appear in the apps list.

On the emulator, :

> [2010-11-12 11:49:49 - HelloTabWidget] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
>
> [2010-11-12 11:55:46 - HelloTabWidget] Success!
>
> [2010-11-12 11:55:46 - HelloTabWidget] \HelloTabWidget\bin\HelloTabWidget.apk installed on device
>
> [2010-11-12 11:55:46 - HelloTabWidget] Done!

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="martin.HelloTabWidget"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
       <activity android:name=".HelloTabWidget" android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>
       <activity android:name=".ArtistsActivity" android:label="ArtistsActivity"> </activity>   
       <activity android:name=".AlbumsActivity" android:label="AlbumsActivity"></activity>
       <activity android:name=".SongsActivity" android:label="SongsActivity"></activity>  
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
</manifest>
```